# Null when passing data to ViewModel

Tags: android

So I have a `ViewModel` that retrieve query for search API. For that, I also have `SearchView` but when typing the first letter on `SearchView` the app crashed because `KotlinNullPointer` on this line inside retrofit

`resultsItem?.value = resultsItemList as List<ResultsItem>?`

I think I have done everything right, I tried

1. Creating own method to pass data to ViewModel
2. Using intent to pass data to ViewModel
3. Defining default value inside ViewModel which works, but can't change after defined

**Here is the code for the Fragment**

```
class Search : Fragment() {

var searchAdapter: SearchAdapter? = null
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var model: picodiploma.dicoding.database.picodiploma.dicoding.database.search.adapter.SearchView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_tv)


    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(picodiploma.dicoding.database.picodiploma.dicoding.database.search.adapter.SearchView::class.java)

    return view
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_)
    val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {
            model.query = s
            getViewData()
            return true
        }
    })
}

fun getViewData() {

    model.getData().observe(this, Observer { resultsItem ->

        searchAdapter = SearchAdapter((resultsItem as ArrayList<ResultsItem>?)!!, this.context!!)
        recyclerView.adapter = searchAdapter
        recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    })
}
}
```

**And the ViewModel**

```
class SearchView : ViewModel() {
private val API_KEY = "2e08750083b7e21e96e915011d3f8e2d"
private val TAG = SearchView::class.java.simpleName
lateinit var query: String

companion object {
    var resultsItem: MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>? = null
}

fun getData(): LiveData<List<ResultsItem>> {
    if (resultsItem == null) {
        resultsItem = MutableLiveData()
        loadData()
    }
    return resultsItem as MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>
}


private fun loadData() {

    val apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val responseCall = apiInterface.getTvSearch(API_KEY, query)

    responseCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: retrofit2.Response<Response>) {
            val resultsItemList = response.body()!!.results
            resultsItem?.value = resultsItemList as List<ResultsItem>?
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, t.toString())
        }

    })
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change below line

```
var resultsItem: MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>? = null
```

to

```
var resultsItem: MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>? = MutableLiveData()
```

Put everything inside apply

```
    run{
searchAdapter = SearchAdapter((resultsItem as ArrayList<ResultsItem>?)!!, this.context!!)
        recyclerView.adapter = searchAdapter
        recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: it's stops the null pointer exception but the recyclerview won't show

Comment: Also check model.getData().observer is getting list or not.

Comment: Check in onResponse you are getting data or not.

Comment: how would you go about doing that?

Comment: it's empty from the getItemCount recycler

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you defined `resultsItem` as nullable `MutableLiveData`, but the `List<ResultsItem>` inside your LiveData is not nullable.
So I guess your `resultsItemList` is null when you get response from the server. And you are getting `KotlinNullPointer` because you are trying to assign `null` to notNull value of `resultsItem` LiveData.

Comment: not really familiar with ViewModel. any suggestions?